# Relationship between Users, Employees and Admins in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, relationship

So, I am fairly new to Laravel and cannot figure out the best way to establish this relationship. I have created a restaurant management system, and successfully created a login system with certain roles. Users can have the four roles: Admin, Waiter, Cashier and General.

Admin can access most of the system, waiter and cashier certain parts and "General" users only the timesheet module. This works, however I want the admin to be able to view its employees.

The problem is that I want the admin to be able to create Employees without the requirement for a user account on the system, but I also want that every User account is automatically either an Admin (Admin role) or Employee (Waiter, Cashier and General).

So basically every user is either an Employee or Admin, but every Employee does not have to be a User. And then I want to connect my Timesheet Module to the Employee Module, instead of the User module.

If I'm doing this in a very complicated way and you know something better, please let me know. Or otherwise post a solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hi roles can apply in two different ways. A role can be an authentication method and it could be a type of employee.

It all depends on what you are planning to do with an employee. I believe that you need to sort that out first. Since Roles mostly are defining access to an App, because they have a relationship to Abillities/Permissions.

Connecting you timesheet to the Employee is a correct step. Since Employees do not always need to logon. But it needs to be plannable.

So the timesheet would be timeable_type with a timeable_id. I would do the following, i would create a EmployeeType::class containing the types: Weighter, Cashier, General. And the timesheet table i would use the following.

employee_id since the timesheet belongs to an employee
and employee_type_id since you want to be able to differentiate the type of employee.
you could even do a morphable relation ship for even more flexibillity

So the User::class had the abilities(permissions) and is an active user in your app.
The Employee::class does not have abilities but is an administrative value in your app. So an employee basically can only logon when it has a User::class

So the employee belongs to the User so the employee has a belongs to relation to the user.
and the user hasOne relation to the employee